# Automatic lifetime management in modern C++ doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++

I was trying to demonstrate that modern C++ would automatically delete the object once it is out of scope. And I was using below code to perform the test. But it doesn't really work as expected. According to the memory size showed in Task Manager, it still has 200+MB memory. But once I uncomment `delete stringTest`, the memory reduced to less than 1 MB. Would anyone please help to see what I overlooked here? Thanks a lot.

BTW, Visual Studio 2015 was used in my test.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

class StringTest
{
public:
    std::string StringSample;

    StringTest::StringTest()
    {
        StringSample = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz...";
    }

    std::string StringTest::Substring(int length)
    {
        std::string result = StringSample.substr(0, length);

        return result;
    }
};

void testStringSeveralTimes()
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        auto stringTest = new StringTest();
        // delete stringTest;
    }
}

int main()
{
    testStringSeveralTimes();

    std::cout << "Done." << std::endl;
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: auto does not do what you think. Lookup `std::unique_ptr<>` or `std::shared_ptr<>` and `std:make_unique<>()`

Comment: auto indicates that the type will be chosen "automatically", it isn't linked to memory management : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried to use `StringTest*`, but the result was the same.

Comment: The result is supposed to be the same.

Comment: The cleanup C++ gives you (which is the same for every standard of C++) is that `stringTest` itself is cleaned up when it goes out of scope. Cleaning up the object it points to would defeat the purpose of extending that object's life by dynamically allocating it.

Comment: Thanks drescherjm. I tried `std::unique_ptr<StringTest> stringTest(new StringTest());` and it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 6):

I think I would refrain from using the word "modern C++" until you learn the basics. Until C++11, `auto` was a storage class specifier that meant *automatic* storage duration, which appertains to the pointer variable and not the memory it manages. In C++11, `auto` was repurposed to allow template argument deduction to be performed in variable declarations. `stringTest` is deduced to be `StringTest*`.

The concept you are looking for is RAII and is not new at all. You should use a smart pointer which will manage the memory for you and deallocate it once it goes out of scope like you expect.

```
auto stringTest = std::make_unique<StringTest>();
```

Comment: I was under the impression that C++11 or C++14 will automatically deallocate the memory once the object is out of scope. It turns out that it is true only when we use smart pointers. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Or just `StringTest stringTest;` -- since there's no demonstrated need for a dynamically allocated object here.

Comment: @Shinbo: C++ does do that (always has, long before C++11). But in your case, the object going out of scope is a pointer. The `StringTest` object is dynamically allocated, and has no scope. If you just created a `StringTest` object normally (as demonstrated in my previous comment), it would similarly be destroyed and its memory reclaimed when it went out of scope.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: So for dynamically allocated memory, that's where we should always use smart pointers which is introduced in "modern C++", to ease the deallocation. Right?

Comment: @Shinbo by writing the word `new` you signal that you want to use *manual memory management*, meaning that you must `delete`.  To use automatic memory management, don't write `new`.